# python loop through list with multiple list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a list - scraped & cleaned from a html data table

```
['8', '1', 'X', '308', '134', '157', '46', '237', '107', '58', '843', '137', '26', '549', '---', '---', '---', '---']
['79', '2', '341', 'X', '401', '1148', '687', '1619', '1604', '674', '2504', '1666', '257', '3154', '---', '---', '---', '---']
['18', '3', '132', '356', 'X', '241', '153', '536', '258', '174', '1293', '348', '67', '1056', '---', '---', '---', '---']
['12', '4', '163', '891', '241', 'X', '112', '508', '227', '154', '1481', '321', '54', '747', '---', '---', '---', '---']
['9/2', '5', '39', '370', '120', '90', 'X', '116', '75', '31', '485', '79', '15', '285', '---', '---', '---', '---']
```

Each `[ ]` represents a row of data that I want to save into a db table.  Now, how do I loop through each `[ ]` and treat it as it is a new row? If I do a for loop it doesn’t seem to pick up that each new `[ ]` is a new data row.  I also imagine I have to split each row so that I can properly save the data into the specific db column

Comment: `for row in mylist: add_row_to_database(row)`.

Comment: when you scrape it, make sure it's in proper array of arrays format. `[ [...], [...] ]`

Comment: how do ensure it's in proper format?  here's my scrap code: rows = table.tbody.findAll("tr")
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td') 
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your code from comment section

```
data_list=[]
rows = table.tbody.findAll("tr") 
for row in rows: 
   cols = row.find_all('td') 
   cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
   data_list.append(cols)
```

now use for loop to get each list inside a list like this

```
for li in data_list:
    for data in li:
        print data
```